Can one suppress the generation of js import stubs when processing css with file loader?
I would like to use esbuild content hashing to copy & rename a directory full of CSS files but otherwise not take any action.
But esbuild wants to generate javascript import/export stubs for every css when i use the file loader.
My options look like:
{
    entryPoints,
    bundle: true,
    metafile: true,
    treeShaking: true,
    splitting: true,
    format: 'esm',
    target: 'es2018',
    logLevel: 'silent',
    sourcemap: !env.prod,
    minify: env.prod,
    outdir: env.outDir,
    loader: { '.css': 'file' },
    entryNames: 'compiled/[name].[hash]',
    assetNames: 'css/[name].[hash]',
    chunkNames: 'compiled/[name].[hash]',
    plugins: [onEndPlugin]
}

For each css file processed, I get a companion javascript in the adjacent js directory that looks like:
import "./chunk.L3FT7JIP.js";

// dist/css/challenge.page.css
var challenge_page_default = "../css/challenge.page.PXOBKK3Y.css";
export {
  challenge_page_default as default
};
//# sourceMappingURL=challenge.page.DTEGHPNJ.js.map

Is there an easy way to suppress these stubs or should I just hash and copy/rename the CSS in my own code and leave esbuild to the js?
